# Colouring multiple cells, in different shades, based on original cell value

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to create a macro that will divide a cell value and if the value is more than 7.5, then colour the cell dark green and then keep on colouring the subsequent cells dark green, for instance 2.25 would be 2 cells dark green and the .25 light green. Moreover, if the colour content of the cell, which is to be coloured, is grey then keep on moving the activecell until it is on a cell with no colour.

```
For Each y In rng
    If Not IsEmpty(y) And y > 7.5 And y <> "" And IsNumeric(y) Then 'I am having trouble here
    y.Select
        With ActiveCell.Offset(0, i).Interior
        .Pattern = xlSolid
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorAccent3
        .TintAndShade = -0.249977111117893
        .PatternTintAndShade = 0
    End With

    col = y.Value / 7.5

    Count = Left(col, Len(col) - InStr(1, col, "."))

    For i = 1 To Count

    Do While ActiveCell.Offset(0, i).TintAndShade = -0.149998474074526
    i = i + 1: Count = Count + 1
    Loop

    ActiveCell.Offset(0, i).Select
    With Selection.Interior
        .Pattern = xlSolid
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorAccent3
        .TintAndShade = -0.249977111117893
        .PatternTintAndShade = 0
    End With
    Next i

    Count = Right(col, Len(col) - InStr(1, col, "."))

    If Count > 0 And Count < 25 Then
    ActiveCell.TintAndShade = -4.99893185216834E-02
    ElseIf Count > 26 And Count < 50 Then
    ActiveCell.TintAndShade = 0.799981688894314
    ElseIf Count > 75 And Count < 100 Then
    ActiveCell.TintAndShade = 0.599993896298105
    End If
    Next y

    End If
Next y
```

The macro is for showing workload across the week, with the greyed cells being weekend, so they would need to be skipped.

Comment: What exactly isn't working?

Comment: If Not IsEmpty(y) And y > 7.5 And y <> "" And IsNumeric(y) Then  at the moment it will not click in when y is greater than 7.5

Comment: @Lowpar how is y defined ? are you sure it's getting a numeric value larger than 7.5 ? and not a string showing as 7.5 ?

Comment: @ShaiRado indeed that is a good question, however when I run a =isnumber on a cell with a value it returns a true, in addition the column is formatted as general.

Comment: @Lowpar see my answer below

Comment: You can probably find templates that do something like that without VBA. For example http://www.mlynn.org/?s=excel

Answer (score 2):

When indenting your code, you have an `If` without `End If`, and one `Next y` **too many** (see indent code below)

```
For Each y In rng
    ' ****** you are not closing this If *****
    If Not IsEmpty(y) And y > 7.5 And y <> "" And IsNumeric(y) Then 'I am having trouble here
        y.Select
        With ActiveCell.Offset(0, i).Interior
            .Pattern = xlSolid
            .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
            .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorAccent3
            .TintAndShade = -0.249977111117893
            .PatternTintAndShade = 0
        End With

        col = y.Value / 7.5

        Count = Left(col, Len(col) - InStr(1, col, "."))

        For i = 1 To Count

            Do While ActiveCell.Offset(0, i).TintAndShade = -0.149998474074526
                i = i + 1: Count = Count + 1
            Loop

            ActiveCell.Offset(0, i).Select
            With Selection.Interior
                .Pattern = xlSolid
                .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
                .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorAccent3
                .TintAndShade = -0.249977111117893
                .PatternTintAndShade = 0
            End With
        Next i

        Count = Right(col, Len(col) - InStr(1, col, "."))

        If Count > 0 And Count < 25 Then
            ActiveCell.TintAndShade = -4.99893185216834E-02
        ElseIf Count > 26 And Count < 50 Then
            ActiveCell.TintAndShade = 0.799981688894314
        ElseIf Count > 75 And Count < 100 Then
            ActiveCell.TintAndShade = 0.599993896298105
        End If
    ' ****** Next y out of place ******
    Next y

    End If
Next y
```

When isolating the problematic section, the following code worked on my data sheet:

```
Sub test_yRange()

Dim rng     As Range
Dim y       As Range

Set rng = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:D5")


For Each y In rng
    ' working now
    If Not IsEmpty(y) And y > 7.5 And y <> "" And IsNumeric(y) Then
        ' I am passing the If above when a certain cell has a value of 8
        y.Select
        With ActiveCell.Offset(0, i).Interior
            .Pattern = xlSolid
            .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
            .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorAccent3
            .TintAndShade = -0.249977111117893
            .PatternTintAndShade = 0
        End With
    End If
Next y


End Sub
```

Comment: Although it was a useful answer, it did not fully answer the question, as for instance ActiveCell.Offset(0, i).TintAndShade = -0.149998474074526
is not a supported property. As a result, the code will not operate correctly.